# Google Sign-in Server Side Authentication for Android in Nodejs

Tags: android, node.js, google-signin, google-api-nodejs-client

I have created an Android app, which requests "Server auth code" from the user and sends it to Backend which is in Nodejs. Now, I want to authenticate this token with the GoogleSign In API and get 'access-token' and 'refresh-token'.

I can see a sample code in Java/Python here, using library provided by google: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow

I tried to find a similar library for Nodejs, Can you provide a snippet or some package, which can help me with this?